# CakePHP 3: find() with cache

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

About the `get()` method, I read [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#Cake%5CORM%5CTable::get):

> **Like find()** get has caching integrated. You can use the cache option when calling get() to perform read-through caching

But later, in the section dedicated to the `find()` method ([here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#Cake%5CORM%5CTable::find)), the cache is not mentioned, there are no examples for the cache and the `cache` option is not mentioned among the supported options.

So I would like to know: can I use the `cache` option with the `find()` method? If so, how?

Thanks.

---

Thanks to ndm. So:

```
$query = $this->Pages->find('all');
$query->cache('all_pages');

$this->set('pages', $query->all());
```

Or (more simple):

```
$query = $this->Pages->find('all')->cache('all_pages');

$this->set('pages', $query->all());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query builder doesn't suport caching via options, it has a separate method that is to be used, `Query::cache()`, which you'd use like

```
$query = $table->find();
$query->cache('cache_key');

$query->cache('cache_key', 'configName');

$query->cache(function($query) {
    return md5(
        serialize($query->clause('select')) .
        serialize($query->clause('where'))
    );
});

// ...
```

See

- **[Cookbook > Query Builder > Caching Loaded Results](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-loaded-results)**
- **[\Cake\Datasource\QueryTrait::cache()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryTrait.html#_cache)**

`get()` supports caching via an option as that's the only way to configure the internal find call, since it's being executed immediately so that `get()` can return throw possible errors and return an entity.

Comment: Thanks @ndm.
Can I have a full example? I cannot figure out how to use both `cache()` and `find()` methods.

Comment: @MirkoPagliai A full example? Of what exactly? What more do you need to know than what is shown here and exaplained in the docs?

Comment: an example like [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-cache-to-store-common-query-results) (with CakePHP 2.x).

Comment: @MirkoPagliai Well, there's nothing fancy like that necessary with CakePHP 3.x, all you need to do is call the `cache()` method on your query (and maybe create a cache configuration if you don't want to use the default one), the rest is magic :)

Comment: Sorry @ndm, your example is complete, I had misunderstood. I modified my first message.

Comment: How to read the contents of the cache? I used
````Cache::read('cache_key')
````
But it returns some random id

Comment: @shylajhaa The query will read them automatically when it has the corresponding cache key set. Reading it manually will work too as long as you're using the same cache config (second argument of `Query::cache()` and `Cache::read()`).

Answer (score 1):

I have investigated cakephp 3 documentation and other resources for good example of using cache() with queries, but didn't found any (docs gives only short snipped, not full example)

I have very similar problem with my method in my model /src/Model/Table/MetaTagTable.php

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class MetaTagTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Get meta tags from db table
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    function getMetaTags($controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag)
    {
        $hasSearchParamFlag = (int) $hasSearchParamFlag;

        return $this
            ->find()
            ->select(['tag', 'type'])
            ->where(
                [
                    'controller'=> $controller,
                    'action'=> $action,
                    'have_search_param'=> $hasSearchParamFlag,
                ]
            )
            ->all()
            ->cache(
                function () use ($controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag) 
                {
                    return "getMetaTags-$controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag";
                },
                'middle'
            );
    }
}
```

The above example shows me a fatal error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::cache()
```

the [official cakephp 3 doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-loaded-results) doesn't give a full example, about how cache() with query builder works, so using [@ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) answer and trying several different variants of code I made my code working, just moving cache() call before ->all() method calling:

```
function getMetaTags($controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag)
{
    $hasSearchParamFlag = (int) $hasSearchParamFlag;

    return $this
        ->find()
        ->select(['tag', 'type'])
        ->where(
            [
                'controller'=> $controller,
                'action'=> $action,
                'have_search_param'=> $hasSearchParamFlag,
            ]
        )                              
        ->cache(
            function () use ($controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag) 
            {
                return "getMetaTags-$controller, $action, $hasSearchParamFlag";
            },
            'middle'
        )                        
        ->all()
        ->toArray();
}
```

because cache() method belongs to a trait "QueryTrait", and cache() method need to be called for Cake\ORM\Query class, not for Cake\ORM\ResultSet.

Now all working, enjoy!

Comment: Simple, the `all()` method returns a `ResultSetInterface` instance, so you have to call it at last.

p.s. call consecutively `all()` and `toArray()` is redundant