# CakePHP 3.x ORM doesn't use cache data when key exists

Tags: caching, cakephp, redis, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.5.13 with Redis configured as the cache engine:

```
// config/app.php
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Redis',
        'duration' => '+1 hours',
        'prefix' => 'cake_redis_',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6379,
    ],
];
```

I have a table with ~260,000 rows in it and a corresponding Table class called `SubstancesTable.php`. I'm attempting to get the first 5000 rows and then cache the results, so that on subsequent queries, the cached results are used rather than executing the same query:

```
// Controller method
public function test()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $Substances = TableRegistry::get('Substances');

    // Get 5000 rows from table
    $query = $Substances->find('list')->limit(5000);

    // Write to cache
    $query->cache('test_cache_key');

    // Output the results
    debug($query->toArray());
}
```

When I login to Redis (running `redis-cli` through ssh on my webserver), I can see a key has been generated with the name "test_cache_key":

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS * 
1) "cake_redis_test_cache_key"
```

I can also see the serialized data in there using `GET cake_redis_test_cache_key`.

When I execute the above in a browser, there is virtually no difference in the time taken between the cache not existing, and after the cache has been created. I have deleted the cached key in Redis using `DEL cake_redis_test_cache_key` and confirmed it has gone by listing the keys in Redis (`KEYS *`)

Clearly Cake isn't reading from the cache in this situation, even though it's writing to it without problems. Why is this happening?

The documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-query-results) is not clear. Do I need to do something else to get it to read the results from the cache? I've also read [CakePHP 3: find() with cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696575/cakephp-3-find-with-cache) but can't see what's being done differently to what I'm doing above.

Comment: Besides invoking that function and looking at whatever timer, have you done any specific testing to determine that the cache actually isn't being used? Check `\Cake\Datasource\QueryTrait::all()` and `\Cake\Datasource\QueryCacher::fetch()` if you haven't already.

Comment: Not sure how I'd use either of those methods as there's no clear documentation especially when using them for this purpose. What I am sure of is - if the cache was being read - it would speed up the execution time of the script since it shouldn't be touching the database. The execution of the above takes approx 2 seconds. To obtain the data from Redis CLI with `GET cake_redis_test_cache_key` takes a few milliseconds. I don't believe the roundtrip to the webserver would be causing this, it's far more likely Cake isn't reading the cached data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say that you should "_use_" them, but that you should debug them, for example set a breakpoint and look what's happening, ie whether the cache is actually being read, as it's these two methods where that would happen.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what kind of gain you can expect to see with such a query, even if the table had 10 million entries, fetching the first 5000 rows shouldn't require any signifcant amount of time whatsoever, I'd expect that most of the time would be spent with hydrating the results, and with only 5000 records, that might not be very significant. The difference (hydration vs deserialization) might only be hundreths or even thousandths of a second, I gave it a test with 5000 records, and the difference was only `0.05` seconds (`0.07701` uncached vs `0.027` cached).

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting such fast load times (0.07 seconds for 5000 rows). I've posted the full controller method, and all I'm doing is `find('list')->limit(5000)` on a Table and displaying it with a method that has no view (`autoRender` is false). The data being returned consists of a numeric ID and a text field - which is a `varchar(1500)` in MySQL. It's being run from fast webserver and fast network access. I'll try and add breakpoints but I expected the execution time would be reduced significantly by caching the results of the query and having Cake read them.

Comment: The time is only for querying+hydrating/deserializing (and this is on a rather slow local dev server), a complete HTTP request with all the shenanigans would surely take a little longer :)